# How to Add QScintilla Via CMake?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qscintilla

I've tried to use `QScintilla` in order to develop my own text editor. I have been using `QMake` for over 3 years, and I know the way of adding the library is

```
config += QScintilla2
```

But my question is, how to add (or, target link) the library in CMake?

I've tried using `target_link_library(QScintilla)` and it reports "No target named 'QScintilla' found" and something similar. How to resolve it?

By the way, the `QScintilla` installed in my PC is built with `QMake`. I don't know if it is compatible with `CMake` or not.

Comment: A few people have created find modules: https://www.google.com/search?q=qscintilla+cmake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you are correct that CMake and QMake are not inter-compatible. Instead, you should copy-and-paste the results of the building into any folder (in my case it's `lib/qt5_qscintilla`) under the directory containing the CMake file `CMakeLists.txt`, plus the `Qsci` folder for the header files provided by the Riverbank Computing.

For instance, on Windows and Linux, the file is `libqscintilla2_qt5.a`; on macOS, the file is ended with extension `.dylib` (dynamic library, sorry I can't really tell you the file name now).

Then, try this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(TestingScintilla VERSION 1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core)
find_package(QT${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core)
# ... (Exactly same for Gui and Widgets)
set(QSCINTILLA_INCLUDE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib/qt5_qscintilla/include/Qsci")
set(QSCINTILLA_LIBRARY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib/qt5_qscintilla/libqscintilla2_qt5.a")
# Directory may vary. Change them to where your files are located.
include_directories(${QSCINTILLA_INCLUDE_DIR})

# ...
# ...
# ...
target_link_libraries(TestingScintilla PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets)
target_link_libraries(TestingScintilla PRIVATE ${QSCINTILLA_LIBRARY})
```